# Save jQuery 'rand color' to local storage?

Tags: javascript, php, session, local-storage

I am building a sticky note pad web application for a college unit. It basically works that everytime, you click add note, it will load one of three colors - please see my javascript below. From here it loads with one of the colors, but everytime I refresh it loads one of the three different colors, how can I save the current note color to the local storage or a php session?

Someone please help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var colors = ["#f1c40f","#e74c3c","#9b59b6"];                
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length);           
  $('.note').css("background-color", colors[rand]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Saving to `localStorage` is easy:

```
localStorage.setItem('someKey', 'someValue');
```

And retrieving the value later is easy too:

```
var val = localStorage.getItem('someKey');
```

The trick in your case is finding the right place in the application lifecycle to save the value (e.g. does the user select a value?).

But to load on startup:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var val = localStorage.getItem('someKey');
    $('.note').css("background-color", val);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to jQuery - how would I go about setting the key and value for this. Thanks for the answer, I'm sure it will work. I put my trust in you.